# Unable to access Jenkins from another mac

Tags: jenkins

We set up Jenkins running on our mac at address 10.20.xx.xx:8080

From the same mac, using localhost:8080 can access Jenkins

But from other machines in the network

10.20.xx.xx:8080/ doesn't load the Jenkins page.
Yet, we can ping the machine.

How do we configure so it can be accessed from outside?

Answer (score 0):

This was because our systems are behind a proxy. Had to whitelist our Jenkins server IP in the mac

System preferences> Network > Ethernet|Advanced... > proxies > Bypass proxy settings

[image]